# A problem repeatedly occurred when reopening PWA in iOS/Safari

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps, quasar-framework

I'm developing a PWA (VueJS/Quasar) and, from time to time, face the following error when re-opening the app (saved on the home screen) after a while.

Black screen with: `A problem repeatedly occurred on "https://..."`

I have found some hints (memory/performance, css issues) and related questions (e.g. [iOS safari crashing (a problem repeatedly occured)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52595504/ios-safari-crashing-a-problem-repeatedly-occured)) but I have not fully understood how to trace down that problem.

1. Does anyone have a clear idea on how to tackle it? As said, it only happens once in a while.
2. While preventing the error in the first place is a priority, is there anything I can do to e.g. reload the app once this error occurs or is this fully out of my control as the app has crashed anyway?