# Debugging a iOS Safari crash "A problem repeatedly occurred"

Tags: javascript, iphone, debugging, safari, crash

Sometimes when visitors visit our website on their iPhone and start scrolling, Safari will show an error "A problem repeatedly occurred for ...." . When we try to reproduce the issue, nothing shows in the console log and we can't seem to find a crash report.

Is there any way to debug this issue further? When reloading the page, and doing the same action, will sometimes not result in the same error.

Tried to use developer tools via Safari on Mac. This shows nothing in the console errorwise.

Sidenote: on desktops and other mobile devices, we don't seem to have this issue.

Comment: I have the same issue. This started occurring since the last iOS update 16.4.1. When scrolling the page quickly, I would first get an automatic page reload, then get the "A problem repeatedly occurred" message. It is to be noted that I have a bunch of ajax/xhr requests triggered on scroll with IntersectionObserver to load additional content, and this error seems to be mostly happening on pages with those.

Comment: Ah yes, that sounds like the same issue! With us it also has lazy loading on our pages

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds like its caused by high GPU consumption.

### Test

Open your web page in Safari, and in dev tools look for the Layers panel. This opens up a lovely interactive 3d view of the 'layers' on your page. Layers are essentially elements which require separate composition. There are many factors which can trigger this, and handily in the 3d view if you click on a layer, it'll tell you the reason for that particular layer being composited. It'll also show you the GPU used to composite that layer.

As you interact with your page, you'll see these values update in real-time. This is really useful since you can see whether interactions and animations cause significant spikes.

If you want a clearer idea of how a real device is impacted, you can plug an iPhone in to your laptop, and use remote dev tools in desktop Safari to get the same Layers view.

### Common causes

- use of position: fixed/sticky CSS properties
- use of CSS 3D transform properties (e.g. translateZ, translate3d)
- use of filter CSS property
- use of will-change CSS property
- use of -webkit-overflow-scrolling CSS property
- use of backface-visibility: hidden
- animation of transform or opacity CSS properties
- iframe elements
- element overlapping another compositing layer (implicit compositing)
- element clipping a compositing descendant (implicit compositing)

See this Chromium code for a peek under the hood: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/WebKit/Source/platform/graphics/CompositingReasons.h;drc=a30d423812ad0d766e93b0f3a53523807b50b17b

*Something that's not completely clear from the above is that content overflowing the body on the x-axis can cause GPU spikes during scroll events.*

Note also that as a user scrolls, pinch-zooms (particularly), etc. your page, rapid redraws of these composited layers is required, because everything requires a re-render to remain sharp, since these layers are essentially bitmapped RGBA PNGs.

Generally speaking, the larger the dimensions of the element, the more GPU is required. Which makes sense but the interesting thing about this is that you'll likely see the issue more on larger devices and/or devices with higher-density displays, e.g. Pro/Max/Ultra models of iPhone.

### How to fix

Hopefully the above will give you an idea of what causes your issue, and you can use the evidence to start mitigating the problem. Any fixes will entirely depend on your code but in general you'll be looking to remove the number of composited elements.

It's absolutely impossible to have no composited layers (the document root is one...) but if you have an abundance of large ones (e.g. full-page modals) then you'll have a good place to start.

In general you might consider the following:

- Don't render (`display: none`) composited elements which aren't visible. For example, techniques like simply moving elements off-screen until they're required.
- If you're using React, ensure that modals, toasts, etc. utilise a React Portal - this will put all elements in a single container, reducing implicit composition.
- If you have an abundance of elements which are inherently composited (e.g. videos, iframes) utilise some logic to reduce the number of these on page at once. For example with a video, don't render the video element until a thumbnail is clicked.
- If you use fixed positioning for elements, is there any opportunity to switch to absolute?
- If you happen to use large, semi-transparent, single-colour elements (e.g. a full-page, semi-transparent backdrop) you can create these as tiny elements, say 5×5px and scale it up using a CSS transform. The GPU requirement will be for a 5×5px bitmap rather than the full screen, e.g. something like 2556×1179px.

I've dealt with this problem myself (GPU on one of our pages was peaking at 550mb, and is now 12mb) so if you have any questions feel free to reach out via. a comment.

Comment: This was an amazing description! I've selected this for future reference.

Comment: Top tier answer, learned so much tricks from this! You solved a bug that was driving the company I work for crazy for a while now

Comment: @milehighsi, I am also having this issue and would like to hire you to fix it if possible. How can I get in touch with you?

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you! Had recent iOS Safari throwing this. Ended up being CSS related - We had too many composited layers.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue happening since the last iOS update and figured out it was a memory issue caused by CSS opacity transitions happening while the content was loaded dynamically, which caused the iOS browsers to act this way. I first removed all CSS animations on the content and then added `will-change: opacity;` to the dynamically loaded content and it solved the problem.

You could try monitoring the performance of your page using the inspector tool and see if the crash is happening while animations are being triggered. If so, maybe try disabling the CSS code. If this fixes the issue but you want to keep the animations, you could look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change.

From what I gathered, this browser crash was caused by a memory issue, which is a little vague. CSS animations could be the cause of this, but there can be many other memory-intensive tasks at fault here.